# Walmart OAuth Authentication (Token API) on vba

Tags: xml, vba, vb.net, walmart-api

I am trying to authenticate to walmart.com using Token-based authentication (New preferred method) on vba. You can read more here: https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#introduction

What can be the reason for the error message? How to fix this error? After all, Consumer id is not required in the code.

Base64EncodeString is my personal function. I checked how it works by comparing the result with web resources.

WalmartAPIUserKey - my ClientID

WalmartSecretKey - my ClientSecret

```vb
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60    
Dim encodeData As String

encodeData = Base64EncodeString(WalmartAPIUserKey & ":" & WalmartSecretKey) 
xmlhttp.Open "POST", "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/token", False                       
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "WM_SVC.NAME", "Walmart marketplace"
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID", "123456abcdef"
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & encodeData
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
xmlhttp.send

MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)
Debug.Print (xmlhttp.responseText)

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

However, I get the following error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:errors xmlns:ns2="http://walmart.com/">
    <ns2:error>
        <ns2:code>SYSTEM_ERROR.GMP_GATEWAY_API</ns2:code>
        <ns2:description>consumer id not found in PRS</ns2:description>
        <ns2:info>System encountered some internal error.</ns2:info>
        <ns2:severity>ERROR</ns2:severity>
        <ns2:category>DATA</ns2:category>
        <ns2:causes/>
        <ns2:errorIdentifiers/>
    </ns2:error>
</ns2:errors>
```

Comment: You noted that tokens have a 15min lifespan?  Don't know if that applies to your side of the process. Weird - consumer id relates to the old style authentication method.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. However, I always get an error (even after 15 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a side note but there should be a grant type sent by the looks of it i.e. body in send line should be

```
grant_type=client_credentials
```

Info:

```
Request Parameters
Name        Description                             Required      Default        
grant_type  The type of access token to be issued   Yes     client_credentials        

** Note:The value of the grant_type should always be 'client_credentials' to get the correct access token **
```

Comment: Do you think I need to add the line:
 xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "grant_type", "client_credentials" ? 

The error is the same.

Comment: I think it needs to go in the body against the .send "xyz"

Comment: without the brackets. I don't know if it needs to be encoded. You may need to encode it first.

Comment: Dim s As String
    s = "grant_type = authorization_code"
    
    xmlhttp.send s

The same error

Comment: "grant_type=client_credentials" - no space

Comment: Unfortunately, I get all the same error message.
Is it possible that Walmart cannot find a consumer id that meets my ClientID and ClientSecret?

Comment: Sounds plausible. Certainly worth checking with them direct.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Walmart Token API](https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#getToken) You need to pass `grant_type=client_credentials` as `request body` to get an `access_token` for other API calls.